# Different fieldsets in Django Admin site depending on user group

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

In my django admin site I want to hide some fields to users within a group (Controllers group)

What would be the best approach? Can we do something like this?

This is my code, but it doesn't work:

admin.py:

```
class PriceFile(admin.ModelAdmin):
    if User.groups.filter(name='Controllers').exists():
        fieldsets = [(None, {'fields':['print_url', ('model', 'client'), 'description']})]  
    else:
        fieldsets = [(None, {'fields':['print_url', ('model', 'client'), 'description', 'total_sum', 'margin_percent', 'final_price']})]
```

Answer (score 8):

Did you already solve this?

Django Admins has a method called `get_fieldsets` which you can use to decide which fieldset you can use to add. Your could would look like the following:

```
@admin.register(ModelName)
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.superuser_fieldsets
        else:
            return self.staff_fieldsets

    staff_fieldsets =  (
        (None, {'fields': ('regular_field_a', 'regular_field_b')})
    )

    superuser_fieldsets =  (
        (None, {'fields': ('regular_field_a', 'regular_field_b')}),
        (None, {'fields': ('super_user_field_a', 'super_user_field_b')})
    )
```

The function `get_fieldsets` has access to the request and object, and what I do here is depending on the status of the user (`is_superuser` in this case) we serve out a different fieldset. You can add in your own requirements, e.g. if a user is part of a authentication group, or if it depends on the object your are seeing.

Comment: Boris, you cannot believe how hard this information was to find using Google. Thank you so much. This did what I wanted in a minute. There are so many more difficult solutions being proposed online.